# Отобразить данные с JSON. Node JS

Tags: json, node.js, rest, render

Забрал данные с url. Отобразил в консоли, теперь хочу отобразить на странице, только чтоб под каждый элемент ( с уникальным id ) создавался элемент списка.
Честно говоря с Node JS до этого не работал, не совсем понимаю каким образом происходит рендер элементов, пытался с помощью `res.end()`, но не вышло.
Буду благодарен за помощь

```
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');
var static = require('node-static');
var url = require('url');
var querystring = require('querystring');

http.get('http://public.api.openprocurement.org/api/2.4/tenders?offset=2018-01-05T21:02:46.167030+02:00', (res) => {
    const {statusCode} = res;
    const contentType = res.headers['content-type'];

    let error;
    if (statusCode !== 200) {
        error = new Error('Request Failed.\n' +
            `Status Code: ${statusCode}`);
    } else if (!/^application\/json/.test(contentType)) {
        error = new Error('Invalid content-type.\n' +
            `Expected application/json but received ${contentType}`);
    }
    if (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
        res.resume();
        return;
    }
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    let rawData = '';
    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        rawData += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', () => {
        try {
            const parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);
            console.log(parsedData);

        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e.message);
        }
    });

}).on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(`Got error: ${e.message}`);
});

function accept(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    });
    res.end("OK");
}

http.createServer(accept).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это если на чистом `NodeJS`. Если нужна одна страничка то этого может хватить. Если нужен полноценный сайт то таки придется смотреть в сторону `express`.

Касательно того что у вас не получилось вернуть данные с `res.end()`, насколько позволяют мои телепатические способности предположить, Вы передавали в `end()` не существующую переменную `parsedData` (не существующую в рамках функции `accept` но существующую в коллбеке Вашего `http.get` запроса). Чтобы все отработало нужно поменять алгоритм.

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer((request, response) => {
  http.get('http://public.api.openprocurement.org/api/2.4/tenders?offset=2018-01-05T21:02:46.167030+02:00', (res) => {
    const { statusCode, headers } = res;
    const error = validate(statusCode, headers['content-type']);
    if (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
      return res.resume();
    }
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    let rawData = '';
    res.on('data', chunk => rawData += chunk);
    res.on('end', () => {
      try {
        makeResponse(response, JSON.parse(rawData).data)
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e.message);
      }
    });
  }).on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(`Got error: ${e.message}`);
  });
}).listen(8080);

const validate = (statusCode, contentType) => {
  if (statusCode !== 200)
    return new Error(`Request Failed. Status Code: ${statusCode}`);
  else if (!/^application\/json/.test(contentType))
    return new Error(`Invalid content-type. Expected application/json but received ${contentType}`);
  return false;
}

const makeResponse = (res, data) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(getHTML(data));
}

const getHTML = (data) => (
  `<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ol>${(() => data.map(data => `<li>${data.id}</li>`).join(''))()}</ol>
  </body>
  </html>`
);
```

Comment: большое спасибо, я пока не дошел до express, т.к не разобрался достаточно в самой node js

Comment: @VladTeryoshin немного обновил ответ. может поможет для понимания

Comment: да, все , как вы предпологали ) спасибо большое за подробный ответ, я попробую еще раз это переписать сам, но пользуясь примером

Answer (score -1):

Смотри фреймворк express. Это просто, быстро и со вкусом + много инфы в гугле.
Скринкаст по node.js и express http://learn.javascript.ru/screencast/nodejs

Comment: мне не понятен выход из конкретной ситуации, спасибо, но для такого ответа можно было бы написать в комментарии
и, если можно, минуту видео где про такое рассказывается в скринкасте, а то я пролистывал и не видел